# Hanging pictures/mirrors to drywalls without leaving big holes

Tags: screws, drywall-anchor

What are the best methods (screws, hooks, etc) to hang **heavy objects** (such as huge mirrors and framed pictures) on drywalls while doing the **less possible damage**?

I don't mind drilling holes in the drywalls, but since I have tons of stuff to hang, it would be nice to avoid leaving enormeous holes everywhere in the apartment.

For example, I got these two **17lbs & 10lbs** framed paintings that I hanged using [these hooks](https://www.lowes.ca/wall-hooks/cobra-2662-white-large-wall-driller-picture-hook_g1199821.html), but sadly this left a pretty big hole in the wall when I chose to move the paintings elsewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Removing self-drilling drywall screw anchors is a bad idea. The hole will be huge. depending on how you do it. Generally, you want to cut the head/lip off, or push it in flat, then spackle right on top. If you really want you can push it into the wall so it falls out INSIDE the wall. **you never want to pull it out** See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUzfOLzRIPc or http://www.debbie-debbiedoos.com/2013/08/a-quick-tip-on-painting-and-patching-walls.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a monkey hook.  they work really well for items that are heavy.  just use multiple hooks for heavier items

http://www.leevalley.com/en/hardware/page.aspx?p=52367&cat=3,40914,50630,52367

Answer (score 0):

If the objects can be hung (hanged?) in close proximity to each other and at the same height attaching a board to the wall first to which the objects can be attached to would decrease the amount of openings left by individual fasteners. This is rarely the case though. For each object that is fairly light weight (1-5 pounds) any wall anchor will do, but the ones that leave the smallest openings are the nail and hook-type picture hangers. They range in size to accommodate a variety of weights and the nail used to fasten them to the wall is miniscule compared to other wall anchors. For heavier objects try to secure them to the framing behind the wall surface (to the wall studs). Use an appropriate length screw drilled on a slight upward angle. It will leave a small opening also that can be easily filled with patching compound.

Comment: Objects get hung, criminals get hanged.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell how big the hole was left from the anchors in your link, but I have had great luck with large mirrors and hangings using "molly" anchors along with a substantial metal hook and picture wire. These hold **a lot** of weight in drywall yet are easy to cover with just a small dab of spackle.

The key is to just tap them under the paper surface of the drywall when patching.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To hang lots of things, with the least amount of damage. You might want to consider  picture rail molding.

[image]

It's a molding run around the room, where pictures can be hung from using wire/string/rods/etc.  It has the advantage that it can be securely fastened to the framing, and allows lots of things to hang with minimal damage to the wall.